# Retrieve the most frequently used name

Tags: f#

I can't get the idea. How to find the most frequently used name e.g.

```
type person = {name:string; surname:string}

let persons=[{name:"Jack";surname:"YYY"};
             {name:"Joe";surname:"XYX"};
             {name:"Jack";surname:"XXY"}]
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// You have to use '=' instead of ':' between field names and field values
let persons = 
    [ {name = "Jack"; surname = "YYY"};
      {name = "Joe"; surname = "XYX"};
      {name = "Jack"; surname = "XXY"} ]

// val it : string = "Jack"
persons |> Seq.countBy (fun {name = s} -> s)
        |> Seq.maxBy snd
        |> fst
```